# Does Locust make use of IP Spoofing?

Tags: locust

I'm running locust load test against my server, which has Cloudflare limit of 250 requests per second per IP (user). And I'm hitting that limit with following locust config:

- Users: 100
- RPS is around 100

So, the question arises here is:

> Does Locust make use of IP spoofing to bypass the DNS limitations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Locust make use of IP spoofing to bypass the DNS limitations?

No, it does not.

But if you actually meant to ask "*Could* Locust make use of IP spoofing?" the answer is yes, see https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/376

Regarding your actual core problem (DNS limits), there should be better solutions though. Check out https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1614 (although the user who filed that didnt seem to get my proposed solution to work...)